# Fuzzy matching with bespoke function gives incorrect length of the output

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-cleaning, matching, fuzzy

In the code below, I have a function called correct_admin_names that takes in main_data, shapefile_data, and the variable they have in common, var_by. The goal of this function is to correct the variable they have in common in main_data by matching it with shapefile_data. However, the length of the output from correct_admin_names() does not match the length of the original data given (it currently gives a length of 1402, but I expect it to be 1420). I want it to match the columns during recycling and not just repeat the values, as the main column is different throughout. Can someone help me fix this code?

```
# Load the required packages
library(dplyr)
library(cli)
library(stringi)
library(fuzzyjoin)


  # create dummy data
  main_data <- data.frame(
    var2 = rep(1:10, each = 142),
    adm2 = paste0("District_", 1:1420),
    value = rnorm(1420)
  )
  
  # create shapefile data
  shapefile_data <- data.frame(
    var3 = rep(1:10, each = 10),
    adm2 = paste0("District_", 1:100),
    region = paste0("Region_", rep(1:10, each = 10))
  )
  
  # function to call
  correct_admin_names <- function(main_data, shapefile_data, match_var,
                                  method = c("jw"),
                                  ignore_case = TRUE,
                                  max_dist = 0.27) {
    
    # to simplify text
    
    text_simplify <- function(x) {
      
      gsub(
        "[[:punct:][:space:]]",
        "",
        tolower(stringi::stri_trans_general(x, "latin-ascii"))
      )
    }

    # Mutate the shapefile_data dataset to create the variable to check
    shapefile_data_mutated <- shapefile_data %>%
      mutate(match_var_y = {{ match_var }}) 
    
    # Select the common variable and the variable to check from shapefile_data
    shapefile_data_select <- shapefile_data_mutated  %>% 
      as.data.frame() %>%
      select({{ match_var }}, match_var_y) 
    
    # Join the two datasets by the common variable
    joined_data <- left_join(main_data, shapefile_data_select, by = match_var, multiple = "all")
    
    # Filter for rows where the selected variable from shapefile_data is missing
    missing_data <- joined_data %>%
      filter(is.na(match_var_y)) %>% pull({{ match_var }}) %>% unique()
    
    # Fuzzy match the missing data against the shapefile data
    fuzzy_match <- missing_data %>%
      # turn into a data.frame
      as.data.frame() %>%
      # simplify the text for matching
      mutate(simplified_text = text_simplify(missing_data)) %>%
      # rename the column to adm2
      rename_with( ~ {{ match_var }}, 1) %>%
      # perform fuzzy join using stringdist_left_join from fuzzyjoin package
      stringdist_left_join(shapefile_data_select %>% mutate(simplified_text = text_simplify(!!sym(match_var))), 
                           by = c("simplified_text"), ignore_case = ignore_case, max_dist = max_dist, method = method) %>%
      # drop the rows that repeat
      distinct() %>%
      # drop the cols that repeat
      select(main_data = .data[[paste0(match_var, ".x")]],
             shape_data = .data[[paste0(match_var, ".y")]],
             # simplified_match_main = .data[[paste0("simplified_text.x")]],
             # simplified_match_shape = .data[[paste0("simplified_text.y")]]
      ) %>% 
      as_tibble() %>% 
      select(adm2 = main_data, shape_data)  
    
    
    # Replace the main_data with the corrected names from the lookup_table
    corrected_main_data <- main_data %>%
      as.data.frame() %>%
      left_join(., fuzzy_match, by = {{ match_var }}, multiple = "all") %>% 
      select(shape_data)
    
    return(corrected_main_data)
    
  }
  
  # Call function
  main_data %>% 
    mutate(adm2_clean = correct_admin_names(. , shapefile_data,  method = 'jaccard', match_var =  'adm2', max_dist = 0.19))
```

Comment: I didn't get deep into it but this seems problematic : `match_var =  'adm2'`, you're passing a string and then in the function using `mutate(match_var_y = {{ match_var }})` which will set `match_var_y` to a constant, and `{{}}` don't do anything there

Comment: Also you might not put library calls inside of a function in general, and avoid using SuppressWarnings() and SuppressMessages() on top of big chunks of code, your code will be more robust when you dress this output rather than just hide it

Comment: On a second look I confirm it's an issue with {{ }}, in fact this code doesn't work. You might spend some time understanding how {{ }} works and the different between passing naked variable names and strings. join functions need a string in `by` unless you use `join_by()`, so I think using `match_var = adm2` (no quotes) and `join_by()` will get you closer. To get a proper answer you'd need a smaller example with expected output.